# How to programatically check if an application is installed or not using JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, installation, serverside-javascript

I have an ASPX page within which I have javascript code. I want to check wheather a particular application is installed in a system or not from my JavaScript code? 
Can any one kindly let me know how to achieve this in javascript. I want to check if a particular version of flash player is installed in my system or not?

(My java script is on server side & it should find if an application is installed in client machine or not)

Thanks IN Advance.

Comment: What SSJS solution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, the javascript is not on your serverside. As it will be called on the client side.

I would recommend [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to determine if Flash is installed or not. I use it and it works pretty well.